# Identifying and counting text in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tab delimited file and I'm trying to pull specific information from it. Essentially, I want to search each line, find an identifier, and then count how many times that appears in the text. I wanted to loop through the text and store the information in a dictionary..

Here's what I have so far:

```
c_count = {"c1":0, "c2":0, "c3":0, "c4":0, "c5":0}

analysis = open("myInputFileName")

for x in c_count:
    if line in analysis == x
        c_count[x] = c_count[x] + 1

        print c_count
```

I get the error:

```
    if line in analysis == x
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong..? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a `:`

```
if line in analysis == x:
                        ^
                        |
```

Try something like this:

```
c_count = {"c1":0, "c2":0, "c3":0, "c4":0, "c5":0}
with open("myInputFileName") as analysis:
    for line in analysis:            #read lines one by one
       line = line.strip()           #strip white-spaces
       if line in c_count:           #if line is found in c_count, increase it's count
          c_count[line] += 1
```

Comment: ahhh thank you so much. That example was very helpful. And sorry about the novice mistake--I only just started learning python this week.